# Using soft dailer in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, tapi

I developed a Call Centre module using Classic ASP. What I have on my page are multiple telephone numbers. Next to each I would like a "button" that once pressed takes the number in that line and calls through the PABX. I looked at TAPI but with limited knowlegde of .Net I didn't get far. Where can I get a "plugin" or a good example on how to do this please?

Comment: classic asp or .net won't help you here as you are on the client side. you have to find some Kind of plugin for your browser that can caommunicate with the telephone

Answer (score 0):

One member of our team solved this problem in a novel way (though it probably won't be what you're looking for).  They used [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) through the PC speaker to dial the number (i.e. hold the mouth piece against the speaker to call the required number).  I'm sure that if you perform a search you'll be able to get hold of the actual tones as wav files or whatever.

Alternatively, you could use ASP.NET to generate the tones directly. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7474/Sound-Generator-How-to-create-alien-sounds-using-m) should make a good starting point.

Comment: I'm already making alien sounds without that link. I wasn't sure this post was actually from 2014.. telephony .. gurgh

Comment: Ha!  That's why I just didn't get involved. I'm going to have enough issues shortly using a network fax to fax documents to specific organisations... Joy! Good luck @Mvision!  ;o)